# && gets ignored when trying to grep several files

Tags: if-statement, grep

Im trying to grep in several different files, using different type of matching. But for some reason it seems it ignores the arguments after &&.

```
$ grep -E -i "err|warn" h2_backups.log storagefolder_backups.log
$ grep -E -i 'err|warn' exports.log imports.log
exports.log:err
$ grep -E -i "err|warn" h2_backups.log storagefolder_backups.log && grep -E -i 'err|warn' exports.log imports.log
$ grep -E -i 'err|warn' exports.log imports.log && grep -E -i "err|warn" h2_backups.log storagefolder_backups.log
exports.log:err
```

As you can see, the first grep contains no error but the second grep does. On the third line I used the grep with no error match first, and this ignores everything after &&. On the forth line I've switched places of the greps and now I get a match (however it probably still ignores everything after &&).

Using && seems to work on my other servers. Any thoughts what might cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the normal behaviour as per the short-circuit evaluation. You are doing `command1 && command2`. If `command1` returns False, then `command2` will not be evaluated because the whole condition is already False.

---

See in a very simple example:

```
$ cat a
hello
```

`grep "hello"` returns something, while `grep "bye"` does not:

```
$ grep "hello" a
hello
$ grep "bye" a
$
```

Hence the behaviour when adding `&& echo "yes"`:

```
$ grep "hello" a && echo "yes"
hello
yes
$ grep "bye" a && echo "yes"
$
```

Comment: It might be worth saying that this is called "short-circuit evaluation".